# Fastreport in Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7

Tags: c++, report, c++builder, fastreport, c++builder-xe7

I am Having an issue when I add a SUM on Fast report. It works fine when I preview it but if its on runtime I get "Access violation at address 0083452C in module 'fs21.bpl'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by including the fast report package.